# Why does "ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML" already have an error?

Tags: android-studio

[Also I can't see the split mode. And gradle build takes too long to finish. I'm a beginner so I badly need help. Thank you in advance. :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9jYV.png)

Comment: First, enable the internet and make your `Gradle sync prosess` complete.

Comment: usually how long is it to finish the gradle sync? I've been waiting for an hour now. Also, I don't have a problem on the internet, my internet has 100mbps.

Comment: Just close the project and open it again. If `Gradle sync prosess` does not start again then go to  `FILE > Sync Project with Gradle File` and wait until `sync` finishes.

Comment: There's no Sync Project with Gradle File on FILE section tho..

Comment: this error is usually shown when the Gradle project does not sync properly. Because I also faced this problem when my grade project does not sync properly. try one more method, go to `File > Invalidate Caches...` and restart again. hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, bro. I will update you when it works. ^^

Comment: ok, don't forget to share with me how you solved this issue!

Comment: UPDATE: Still doesn't work. I'm kind of desperate rn. I have to finish my activities on time.

Comment: UPDATE: lol it works now. I just invalidate cache for the second time and then I don't know what happens but it works now.